# Use sed command in python

Tags: python, linux

How to use subprocess.call() in python for long linux command. Like if I want to edit a file call records.txt by replacing all the comma with whitespace in linux shell, I can:

```
tr ',' ' ' < records.txt
```

How to use that with python in subprocess.call().
Thanks

Comment: what's wrong with python?

Comment: I just try to play with convert between python and linux command

Comment: @AvinashRaj In my case I needed to do complex text manipulation of files but I also needed access to some variables inside the Python program. In this case running `sed` inside the Python program was the best option for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

records.txt:

```
jflaskdzhuskajkdkhdsa,dakssdsd,s,a,sa,sas,s,,sas,wwq,wq,wq,w,q,wq,wq,,wq,wq,e,d,rdsa,s,aa,ews,,WQD,AS,SA,WRFDSS,
```

python file:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("tr \',\' \' \' < records.txt", shell=True)
```

output:

```
jflaskdzhuskajkdkhdsa dakssdsd s a sa sas s  sas wwq wq wq w q wq wq  wq wq e d rdsa s aa ews  WQD AS SA WRFDSS
```

Comment: That works, thank you. But I dont understand why we need shell=True?

Comment: The shell argument (which defaults to False) specifies whether to use the shell as the program to execute. If shell is True, it is recommended to pass args as a string rather than as a sequence.

On Unix with shell=True, the shell defaults to /bin/sh. If args is a string, the string specifies the command to execute through the shell. This means that the string must be formatted exactly as it would be when typed at the shell prompt.

for more visit :-
https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html